# Using flex of the screen inside a ScrollView

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have this code

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
   <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: 2000}}>
      <Text style={{flex: .5, backgroundColor: 'orange'}}>box1</Text>
      <Text style={{flex: .5, backgroundColor: 'orange'}}>box2</Text>
      <Text style={{flex: .5, backgroundColor: 'orange'}}>box3</Text>
   </ScrollView>
</View>
```

With this, I was hoping for each `<Text />` to occupy half of the screen (therefore, a combination of all the children to equal 1.5 of the screen height). Instead, each box is occupying a third of the 2000 pixel height. Is there anyway of getting my intended result using flex? Or must I calculate the height of the screen and then get the desired % for each `<Text />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another view inside the scrollView and fix its height to be 1.5 times the screen height and then give the text equal flex.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

const App = (props) => {
  let screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

  let bodyHeight = screenHeight*1.5;

  return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.body}>
        <View style={[styles.innerBody, { height: bodyHeight }]}>
          <Text style={{flex: .5, backgroundColor: 'orange'}}>box1</Text>
          <Text style={{flex: .5, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>box2</Text>
          <Text style={{flex: .5, backgroundColor: 'purple'}}>box3</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  innerBody: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 5
  }
});

export default App;
```

I've created a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@s3nt1n3lz24/flex-inside-scrollview-with-fixed-height)

Answer (score 0):

you should use percentage instead of flex